# Color format accepted by Bokeh plots

Tags: python, bokeh

In many Bokeh examples (e.g. the [unemployment chart](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/gallery/unemployment.html), and the [periodic table](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/gallery/periodic.html)), I see that the plotting primitive `rect` receives `color` from `ColumnDataSource` from an HTML representation:

e.g.:

```
....

colors = [
    "#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2", "#dfccce",
    "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"
]

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(month=month, year=year, color=color, rate=rate)
)

p.rect("year", "month", 1, 1, source=source,
    color="color", line_color=None)
```

However, looking at the [documentation of `rect`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/reference/plotting.html?highlight=rect#bokeh.plotting.rect), I don't see a parameter for `color` (note that you are allowed to pass "[line-properties](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/objects.html#userguide-objects-line-properties)" and "[fill-properties](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/objects.html#userguide-objects-fill-properties)" parameters, but none of them accept `color` as a parameter)

Most importantly for this question, is there a different way, other than HTML, to **specify** colors for Bokeh plots? Ideally, I would like to specify colors using the [color palettes](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/color_palettes.html) generated by [`seaborn`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`color` is a convenience argument to the plot glyph methods that sets both `line_color` and  `fill_color` at the same time. Those are the actual arguments, in case you'd rather use them for explicitness, or need to set them independently.

There is also now a `LinearColorMapper` object that you can configure with one of the palettes in `bokeh.palettes` or with your own sequence of colors. You can use this from python to map data into the list of colors for the `ColumnDataSource`.

Note that in an upcoming release (probably 0.8) you will be able to specify a palette/colormapper + column name for the `color` (or `line_color` or `fill_color`) arguments, and then the color mapping will happen on the client (instead of having to send over the possibly large list of colors explicitly)